# Why CopyOnWriteArrayList uses extra memory for set,add operation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

As per my understanding for updating data in CopyOnWriteArrayList. set method is locked using ReentrantLock,data is copied in a local variable,data to be added is added in this local variable then it is updated as whole List data. Is there any advantage of doing this over synchronized version of set method of Vector and synchronizedList

Comment: Did you read the javadocs?

Comment: Why do you assume _"set method is locked using ReentrantLock"_ -- I don't see that anywhere in the API description.  The point of COWAL is to prevent mutations from interfering with in-progress iterations, which pays off when mutations are infrequent and read-only access is common.

Comment: I did not assume,I said as per source code.I have checked source code of CopyOnWriteArrayList in grepcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any advantage of doing this over synchronized version of set method of `Vector` and `synchronizedList`

For example, you cannot iterate over a `synchronizedList` in one thread and modify it in another. You'll get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.
This will never happen with a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`,
because the underlying data structure of an iterator is *never* modified.

The description in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) clearly states the benefits and drawbacks.